# Font "HelveticaNeue.ttf" deviation in android lollipop

Tags: android, fonts, android-5.0-lollipop, android-fonts

I am using "HelveticaNeue.ttf" as a custom font in my android app; with all the previous versions of android it was fine, but with lollipop it is stretching than the usual font, anyone has a solution?

[image: lollipop view is attached below]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=608&thanks=608&ts=1404735239

Especially comment #13 from Nov 3, 2014

I had the same problem and it worked for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem - my ttf fonts squashed/stretched on a Nexus 5 running Lollipop.

This was caused by a problem with the ttf, in particular an invalid idRangeOffset value, which occurred during the creation of the ttf presumably.

I fixed the problem by requesting the original font again from the designers, and recreating the ttf using onlinefontconverter.com.